# how to call a phtml file in the success page in a proper way?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, template

I have a template in `template/checkout/onepage/hello.phtml`

I want to include this phtml file in the success page, i.e `template/checkout/success.phtml`

So I have created a block in the checkout.xml inside the "checkout_onepage_success" handle as:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
         <block type="core/template" name="onepagehello" template="checkout/onepage/hello.phtml"/>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

And this phtml file gets rendered in the success page on the top of the page.

When I write `getChildHtml(onepagehello);` in `success.phtml` page, then nothing comes.

1. I want to know when `getChildHtml()` works and when the block gets rendered ?
2. I want to get "hello.phtml" from `getChildHtml()`, so that I can put this block wherever necessary throughout the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layout is a hierarchy of blocks and `getChildHtml()` can only render the children of the current block.

Right now your hierarchy looks like this:

```
root
+-- content
    +-- onepagehello
    +-- checkout.success
```

but you need this:

```
root
+-- content
    +-- checkout.success
        +-- onepagehello
```

To add a new block to an existing parent block, use `<reference>`:

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="checkout.success">
         <block type="core/template" name="onepagehello" template="checkout/onepage/hello.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Comment: Thank you for the concept @fschmengler.It worked.. I wonder where can I find these simple fundamental concept which makes the base of magento..

Comment: For fundamentals of Magento layout I recommend Alan Storms blog at alanstorm.com. You can also find a  curated list of Magento resources at https://github.com/aleron75/mageres

Comment: what u doing Fabian... you  have impress me day by  day..what explanation..:)

Answer (score 3):

Just add element as="NAME" on your block like this

```
<block type="core/template" name="onepagehello" template="checkout/onepage/hello.phtml" as="hello"/>
```

you can call like this

```
getChildHtml('hello');
```